# Factorisation of twisted polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings, differential-algebra

Let $K=\mathbb{C}((t))$ and let $K_m=\mathbb{C}((t^{1/m}))$. let $K\{x\}$ denote the ring of twisted polynomials. The addition in this ring is defined as usual, but the multiplication is adjusted by the rule
$$
xa=ax+t\frac{d}{dt}a, \quad \quad a\in K.
$$
The following theorem is well-known:

Theorem: Let $p(x)\in K\{x\}$. Then there exists a field extension $K_m$ over which $p(x)$ factors linearly; i.e.,
$$
p(x)=(x-a_1)\cdots (x-a_n),\quad \quad a_i\in K_m.
$$

Perhaps, one can think of this theorem as a twisted analogue of Puiseux's theorem.

Question: how does one prove this theorem?

I have seen one proof in, e.g., [Singer and van der Put's book](https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Galois_Theory_of_Linear_Differential_Equ.html?id=3RjYmm6AAM4C). But this proof is long and complicated uses differential modules. I would prefer a proof that avoids using differential modules, but I am interested in all the proofs that are available.

Comment: Why the theorem is a twisted version of the fact the the complex numbers are algebraically closed and not of Puisseux theorem?